# Android emulator won't boot up

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to install android sdk and run my first application on my PC (Win7 64 bit). I followed instructions on http://developer.android.com from the beginning to http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html When I try to start emulator (as mentioned on the last url) simply nothing shows up.

```
5 - Select the new AVD from the Android Virtual Device Manager and click Start.
```

It doesn't show any error messages. After launching AVD a process named adb.exe appears on task manager.

Below is eclipse console output when try to run my blank app from eclipse. On configurations, I set different target devices and selected starting activity manually. The same problem continues.

**When AVD is started from outside of eclipse**(`\sdk\platform-tools>android avd`):

```
[2013-03-22 08:50:48 - 1st] ------------------------------
[2013-03-22 08:50:48 - 1st] Android Launch!
[2013-03-22 08:50:48 - 1st] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-22 08:50:48 - 1st] Performing com.example.st.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-03-22 08:50:49 - 1st] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AvdTest'
[2013-03-22 08:50:49 - 1st] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AvdTest'
```

**When AVD is started from eclipse**:

```
[2013-03-22 09:22:44 - 1st] ------------------------------
[2013-03-22 09:22:44 - 1st] Android Launch!
[2013-03-22 09:22:44 - 1st] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-22 09:22:44 - 1st] Performing com.example.st.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-03-22 09:22:44 - 1st] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'AvdTest' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2013-03-22 09:22:44 - 1st] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AvdTest'
```

I also downloaded only sdk and installed eclipse plugin but result is the same.

Tried to use logcat also. Started it then started AVD, but logcat shows nothing. When I kill adb.exe from task manager,it kills logcat too.

```
\sdk\platform-tools>adb -e logcat
- waiting for device -

\sdk\platform-tools>
```

After reinstalling IDE/SDK a couple of times I decided to ask it here. What else I can do?

Edit : **Folks, I have a virtual device.** Please stop suggesting adding a virtual device.

[image: Virtual Device Manager]

[image: SDK]

[image: Eclipse]

Comment: create one avd...have you done it

Comment: Are you sure eclipse is looking at the same android SDK location? I seem to recall the ADP being able to download a copy of the SDK itself that it unpacks in your user profile unless you point it elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, once more I checked it from window>preferences>Android>SDK Location and it's the same.

Comment: When I chose the Nexus One emulator, it would not boot up. Switching to the Nexus 4 emulator allowed me to boot up to an android environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it. In event viewer(Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\Event Viewer) clicked on Windows Log>Application on left menu and read error logs.

[image: Event Log]

I googled dll file mentioned in log (`aticfx32.dll`) and found the dll file belongs to ATI graphic cards. My PC has an Intel graphic card. While searching for solution I also found [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64407) web page and applied solution they used. It works like a charm.

Steps:

1. Download your graphics card driver from intel's website
2. Extract the zip somewhere, Location does not matter
3. Go into Device Manager, (type Device Manager in the windows search bar)
4. Click Display Adapters and Intel HD Graphics.
5. Go to the tab labeled "Drivers"
6. Click "Update Drivers" and "Browse my computer for drivers"
7. Click "Let me pick from a list of drivers"
8. Click the Have Disk Button,
9. Navigate to where your extracted drivers are and go into the directory labeled "Graphics"
10. Select the file named "igdlh64.INF"
11. Click on the OK button and then click Next, the drivers should install
12. After that you need to reboot, and after rebooting your drivers should be updated

Comment: Magically This Works. In my case, ntdll.dll file was missing.

Answer (score 72):

I had the similar problem on OSX. My emulator works fine, but after some runs it won't start. I've solved that by :

1. Go to `.android` directory (in my case it was `Users/<username>/.android`
2. Go to `avd` folder
3. Find the emulator that won't start (directory name will be the same as emulator)
4. Remove all `.img` files from there. ***Do not remove*** `.ini` files.
5. Try to run the simulator again.

Comment: I can't believe !! It also solve my Problem, took me hours !

Comment: Timesaver!  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: This worked on Win 10. It also solved my issue of massive idle CPU (60%+) usage by the emulator. It's now back down to < 1% at idle. And I was just about ready to start troubleshooting if the CPU usage was because of my app!

Comment: This failed to work for me because I had .android symlinked to another location from ~/.android.  I was trying to free up space on my mac HDD, but apparently the emulator won't work with a symlinked location =/   Moving .android back to my home directory made the emulator start without issue.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had to delete the file ***cache.img.qcow2*** from my avd device folder (C:\Users\User_Name.android\avd\Device_Name.avd).

Answer (score 3):

I run into this issue at least once every time I try to start a new project, maybe from projects sharing devices. In the following folder:

C:\Users\.android\avd\ (e.g. Nexus_5_API_23.avd)

I had to delete the following files pictured. I tried deleting the `.qcow2` files as one user mentioned without luck. Notice all the files deleted are the newest modified files/folders (see the Date Modified column) that are not `.ini` or `.conf` files.

[image]

**UPDATE:** It seems if I delete just the `snapshots` directory (pictured above), that does the trick too.

Answer (score 3):

I came here beacuse i have same problem, with Android Studio 3.6 and win 10 OS

I fixed that with this steps:

1. Go to AVD Manager
2. Hit `Virtual device configuration` (pencil icon)
3. Hit `show advance setting`
4. Scroll down to Boot options
5. Choose `Cold boot`
6. Hit `finish`

If problem remain same,

1. Hit `drop down` near `pencil` icon
2. `Wipe data`
3. Hit `refresh button` at the right bottom near question mark button

Comment: The second option actually worked for me. What could be the problem?

Comment: IMO It's looks like data problem inside the emulator, so it won't boot up. The emulator works like real device if the problem exist like that, it's called soft brick.

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed any "Target" API?.
Have you configured any "Virtual Device"?

The Log tells you that it can't find 'avdTest' device, it could be because you didn't configure it, or just, it's not present.

Try to setup a device at the Eclipse's "Virtual Device Manager", then, start the virtual device from this menu ( AVD devices -> Start... ) and if it works, then run your code on it.

I don't recommend you using command line for the first time.
Also I recommend you trying with Android 2.3.3 (API 10) for first, because it takes less time time to start the emulator.

Comment: Yes I configured Virtual Device"s" and set target. When log tells it can't find device is when I let eclipse start virtual device. If you check first log I posted, you can see it's a bit different. By the way using command line just brings a window where you can configure/launch virtual devices you set before. It's the same window you can start emulator in eclipse.