# emulator won't show up on mac

Tags: android, macos, emulation

i am having a very similar problem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565028/android-emulator-wont-boot-up). the difference is that i am using a mac (version 10.6.8) to which i am completely new. that's why i don't know how to handle such issues. In addition to the problem defined in that link my graphical layout also won't show up. i'm guessing, though they both are related.

so on the eclipse console it says this , wenn i try to run my app:

```
    [2014-07-01 02:32:38 - propra-fotoapp] Android Launch!
    [2014-07-01 02:32:38 - propra-fotoapp] adb is running normally.
    [2014-07-01 02:32:38 - propra-fotoapp] No activity specified! Getting the launcher 
                                           activity.
    [2014-07-01 02:32:38 - propra-fotoapp] Performing com.example.propra_fotoapp.
                                           MainActivity activity launch
    [2014-07-01 02:32:38 - propra-fotoapp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator 
                                           with compatible AVD 'big_phone'
    [2014-07-01 02:32:38 - propra-fotoapp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 
                                           'big_phone'
```

And regarding my graphical layout, when i click it there is an error message there instead of my layout and it says

> The project target (Android L (Preview)) was not properly loaded.

I've read about many possible solutions like the one with the graphic card, restarting the mac, reinstalling eclipse or killing the adb.exe etc etc. but somehow none of them seem to work for me or don't apply in my case. 
any ideas?

Comment: use bluestack as a emulator it works fine in any version of mac machine

Comment: hmm.. thanks for the tip, but what about my missing graphical layout?

Comment: if ur sdk packages are installed in sdk manager then i think there would be some clean up issue..try restart eclipse or clean project

Comment: that didn't really help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is your problem, I had the same problem and messed around till I got my program to work. In the Graphical Layout on eclipse there is a green android icon with presumably by the error displayed, 20 written next to it. Change it to another number such as 19, representing API 19 and it will save your problem.[image: Snapshot of Graphical Layout]

In the picture, the android icon I spoke about is in the top right of the picture.

Comment: i solved my problem regarding the graphical layout. though the emulator still won't show up. what you wrote above is , if i didn't get you wrong, not for the emulator problem, right?

Comment: Hi Melar,
I tried to solve the "The project target (Android L (Preview)) was not properly loaded." error.

Comment: ok thanks. it definitely helps with that problem. though i still can not find a way of making the emulator show up. no errors no nothing. it just doesn't show up..

Comment: When you run the software it should promt you on which platform to execute the code on (Which emulator or if you want to use an plugged in Android phone). The prerequisite to using an emulator is that you actually set it up, there are many tutorials to help you set one up. If you already have one you can try opening it up via the android command from your SDK's tools/ directory, or via Window SDK and AVD Manager from Eclipse.