# Running Android Studio emulator in Windows 7 with AMD cpu

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I have recently installed AS 2.1.2 on Windows 7 64-bit with AMD cpu fx(tm)- 4300, but could not able to run the AS emulator.

I have downloaded the system image, the one which is highlighted (armeabi-v7a)

[image]

but when I run 
it says **your cpu doesn't support vt-x or svm**

[image: Check screenshot here.]

in the above when I click ok, I see this

[image]

and then nothing happens.

I have restarted the system and enabled the SVM in BIOS settings but with no success.

Now my question is **how do I make this thing work**? Or I need to use a third party emulator like `Genymotion`?

I have found a lot of similar issues but none helped be. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, using Genymotion will be the best choice, because it supports acceleration using Virtualization Technology on AMD. [See requirements](https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/01_Get_Started/Requirements.htm)

Standard AVD supports acceleration using Virtualization Technology on AMD only for Linux.
[See requirements](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#Requirements) . Without acceleration it will be very slow.

Have you tried what is written in your log: disable GPU emulation?
See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36748113/6510908)

Another guess is to check if it's all good with your video drivers.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15571006/6510908)